# Children routes don't work as expected

Tags: angular, routes

Let's say the `AppModule` is the root module of the app.
Its routing file looks like this:

```
...
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: './modules/auth/auth.module#AuthModule',
  }
]
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

`AuthModule` routing file looks like this:

```
...
const authRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'registration',
    loadChildren: './registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'
  }
];
export const authRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(authRoutes);
```

Everything works fine when `LoginModule` routing file looks like this:

```
const loginRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginStep1Component },
  { path: 'a', component: LoginStep2Component }
];
export const loginRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(loginRoutes);
```

But some troubles appear when I try to use some base component to wrap Login components via `<router-outlet>` having the router file as following:

```
const loginRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LoginStep1Component, pathMatch: "full" /*tried also without pathMatch*/ },
      { path: 'a', component: LoginStep2Component }
    ]
  }
];
```

The `localhost:4200/auth` works fine displaying the `LoginStep1Component`.

But `localhost:4200/auth/a` doesn't work. I can't access it and view LoginStep2Component neither via link navigation nor via URL bar of the browser.

I have also tried to replace '' with some path but it didn't help either. I don't consider this as a proper solution.